# How to read the end of a script file as a data file (Perl or any other language)

Tags: ruby, perl, shell

I am looking for the correct syntax of doing the following (in Perl, Shell or Ruby):

```
# variable to access the data lines appended as a file

END_OF_SCRIPT_MARKER

raw data starts here
and it continues.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perl does this with `__DATA__`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while(<DATA>)
{
     print;
}

__DATA__
Text to print
goes here
```

Comment: This is an unauthorized version of copyrighted material. Please don't link to sites with ripped off ebooks.

Comment: @Raoul: Thanks, didn't realise it was ripped off!

Comment: if anyone is interested, the equivalent of `__DATA__` in Ruby is `__END__`

Comment: And `__END__` in Perl is synonymous with `__DATA__` so use either. Of possible related interest: [Inline::Files](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Inline::Files).